# Trouble decrypting openSSL AES CTR encrypted text

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, php-openssl, webcrypto-api

I have trouble decrypting an message encrypted in php with the `openssl_encrypt` method. I am using the new WebCrypto API (so I use `crypto.subtle`).

Encrypting in php:

```
$ALGO = "aes-256-ctr";

$key = "ae6865183f6f50deb68c3e8eafbede0b33f9e02961770ea5064f209f3bf156b4";

function encrypt ($data, $key) {
    global $ALGO;

    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($ALGO), $strong);
    if (!$strong) {
        exit("can't generate strong IV");
    }

    return bin2hex($iv).openssl_encrypt($data, $ALGO, $key, 0, $iv);
}


$enc = encrypt("Lorem ipsum dolor", $key);

exit($enc);
```

example output:

```
8d8c3a57d2dbb3287aca61be0bce59fbeAQ4ILKouAQ5eizPtlUTeHU=
```

(I can decrypt that in php and get the cleartext back)

In JS I decrypt like this:

```
function Ui8FromStr (StrStart) {
    const Ui8Result = new Uint8Array(StrStart.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < StrStart.length; i++) {
        Ui8Result[i] = StrStart.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return Ui8Result;
}

function StrFromUi8 (Ui8Start) {
    let StrResult = "";

    Ui8Start.forEach((charcode) => {
        StrResult +=    String.fromCharCode(charcode);
    });

    return StrResult;
}

function Ui8FromHex (hex) {
    for (var bytes = new Uint8Array(Math.ceil(hex.length / 2)), c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
        bytes[c/2] = parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}

const ALGO = 'AES-CTR'
function decrypt (CompCipher, HexKey) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        // remove IV from cipher
        let HexIv = CompCipher.substr(0, 32);
        let B64cipher = CompCipher.substr(32);

        let Ui8Cipher = Ui8FromStr(atob(B64cipher));

        let Ui8Iv = Ui8FromHex (HexIv);
        let Ui8Key = Ui8FromHex (HexKey);

        crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", Ui8Key, {name: ALGO}, false, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]). then (function (cryptokey){

            return crypto.subtle.decrypt({ name: ALGO, counter: Ui8Iv, length: 128}, cryptokey, Ui8Cipher).then(function(result){
                let Ui8Result = new Uint8Array(result);
                let StrResult =  StrFromUi8(Ui8Result);
                resolve(StrResult);

            }).catch (function (err){

                reject(err)

            }); 
        })
    })
}
```

when I now run `decrypt("8d8c3a57d2dbb3287aca61be0bce59fbeAQ4ILKouAQ5eizPtlUTeHU=", "ae6865183f6f50deb68c3e8eafbede0b33f9e02961770ea5064f209f3bf156b4").then(console.log)` I get gibberish: `SÌõÅ°blfçSÑ-`

The problem I have is, that I am not sure what is meant with `counter`. I tried the IV but failed.

[This Github tutorial](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-ctr---decrypt) suggests*<sup>1</sup>, that it is the IV - or at least part of it, as I've seen people talk about that the counter is part of the IV (something like 4 bytes, that means that the IV is made from 12 bytes IV and 4 bytes Counter)

If that is indeed true, my question then becomes: Where do I give the script the other 12 bytes of IV when counter is only 4 bytes of it.

Can anyone maybe give me a working example of encryption in php

*<sup>1</sup> It says that the same counter has to be used for en- and decryption. This leads me to believe, that it is at least something similar to the IV

Comment: @zaph The output is made out of 32 characters of hex IV (16 bytes) + 24 characters of ciphertext in Base64 (17 bytes)

ciphertext total = 16 + 17 = 33

Comment: @zaph What leads you to believe that the ciphertext is 24 bytes?. As I said it has the IV prepended, but the IV is in Hex. Therefore the cyphertext is just 17 bytes in base 64 (with 16 bytes Hex prependen - that's 32 characters Hex prepended)

Comment: What you have is a mis-mash of hexadecimal encoding for the IV and Base64 encoding the the encrypted data. That is a really bad idea, it certainy confused me and certainly fails the ["Rule of Least Surprise"](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:Principle%20of%20Least%20Surprise?redirect=1), In interface design, always do the least surprising thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are handling the key incorrectly in PHP.

In the PHP code you are passing the hex encoded key directly to the `openssl_encrypt` function, without decoding it. This means the key you are trying to use is twice as long as expected (i.e. 64 bytes). OpenSSL doesn’t check the key length, however—it just truncates it, taking the first 32 bytes and using them as the encryption key.

The Javascript code handles the key correctly, hex decoding it before passing the decoded array to the decryption function.

The overall result is you are using a different key in each case, and so the decryption doesn’t work.

You need to add a call to `hex2bin` on the key in your PHP code, to convert it from the hex encoding to the actual 32 raw bytes.

Comment: You can certainly say that accepting a 64 byte key for AES fails both least surprise and fail fast principles. But yeah, there it is :( .